# In MVC calling webservice with ajax call not working give error code 404?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, http-status-code-404

In my .net framework with MVC calling webmethod like. webservice1.asmx/helloWorld
with Ajax give error 404 not found..In my another server same code working. Is there 
anything missing to call ?? and physical path give me same webserive and webmthod in my .net project.. please help me ..

EDIT

code to call the web service

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "/WebServices/WebService1.asmx/HelloWorld",
   data:"{}",
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   dataType: "json",
   async: false,
   success: function(msg) {
       var data = msg.d;  
   },
   error: function(msg) { 
   alert(msg); 
   }
 });
```

Comment: its hard to see from here how your code looks like, can you post it, how you are calling the webservice and how does your webmethod looks like

Comment: my code simple like calling ajax through webservice example like   $.ajax({ 
                type: "POST",
                url: "/WebServices/WebService1.asmx/HelloWorld",
                data:"{}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                async: false,
                success: function(msg) {
                    var  data = msg.d;
                               
                },
                error: function(msg) {   alert(msg);
                 } 
            });

Comment: check the url if its pointing to a valid resource because 404 specifies the resource you are looking for is not found

Comment: yes URL show me valid when i try to execute physically its working and also same code working on my another server ..so what is the problem here may be MVC installation issue or any-other please help me..

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you have hardcoded the url to the web service in your javascript call instead of using an url helper to generate it. So try like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $.ajax({ 
        type: "POST", 
        url: "@Url.Content("~/WebServices/WebService1.asmx/HelloWorld")", 
        data: "{}", 
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
        dataType: "json", 
        async: false, 
        success: function(msg) { 
            var data = msg.d; 
        }, 
        error: function(msg) { 
            alert(msg); 
        } 
    });
</script>
```

Notice how the url to the web service is no longer `/WebServices/...` but it is generated with an url helper. So if for example you deploy your application in a virtual directory in IIS the helper will take into account this virtual directory.

Comment: the web service is accessible when the OP pastes the url `www.example.com/webservice/webservice1.asmx?op=Helloworld` in the browser, what do you say the `op` has to be provided in the `data` ?

Comment: @john, that will depend on what parameters does the webmethod expect. As far as the `webservice1.asmx?op=Helloworld` url is concerned, that's SOAP and you obviously cannot invoke it using AJAX. The web service will need to be exposed over JSON.